# How can I return 1 row from a subquery in select statement if subquery has more than 1 result?

Tags: mysql, subquery, limit

I have this query:

```
select a.*, b.*, (select c.* from tableC c where c.id_tableA = a.id) from tableA a inner join tableB b on a.id = b.id_tableA where b.id_user = 50;
```

The subquery (which is tableC) is returning me more than 1 row as expected. How can I  return only 1 row from tableC so it could match with the rest of the query?

So far I have tried this:

```
(select c.* from tableC c where c.id_tableA = a.id limit 1)
```

It didn't work as mysql said:

> "Operand should contain 1 column(s)"

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing two things. Scalar subquery in `SELECT` list should return only one value (both row and column). Using `LIMIT 1` will get you one row, but still many columns.
So you could specify column name:

```
select a.*, b.*,
  (select c.col_name from tableC c where c.id_tableA = a.id order by .. limit 1) 
from tableA a 
inner join tableB b on a.id = b.id_tableA 
where b.id_user = 50;
```

or use normal `JOIN`:

```
select a.*, b.*, c.*
from tableA a
inner join tableB b 
  on a.id = b.id_tableA 
left join tableC c
  on c.id_tableA = a.id
where b.id_user = 50;
```

Answer (score 0):

if column id from table C is a primary key then it should have no problem
but if no, try to add another condition that will filter your subquery results like ,

for example here is the start_date:

```
SELECT a.column_1, b.column_2, 
        (SELECT column_3 FROM tableC  
        WHERE (id = a.id 
        AND (start_date = (SELECT MAX(b.start_date) 
             from tableC as c
             where a.id = c.id ))) AS column_3
FROM tableA as a INNER JOIN
     tableB as b ON b.id = a.id
WHERE b.id_user = 50;
```